# CKEditor: Is there a way to limit the characters users can type/paste inside the editor?

Tags: ckeditor

I'm not talking about number of characters but types of character. Can I, for example, restrict my CKEditor instances to numeric and commas or alphanumeric?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this you are searching. You can also check on keyCode only. For more about that please take a look about keycode differences at google.

```
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.document.on('keydown', function(e)
{
    var prevent = {'1','2','3','4','5'}
    var character = null;
    var charCode = (CKEDITOR.env.ie ? e.data.$.keyCode : e.data.$.charCode);
    if(charCode != 0)//Mozilla check
    character = String.fromCharCode(charCode);

    //restriction logic
    if(jQuery.inArray(character, prevent))
    {
       e.data.preventDefault(); // To prevent insert
    }
}
```

But you will always need to define the charcters in this function.. There is no complete solution for prevention of inserting a type of charcters. as far as i know off.

Comment: thanks. I ended up doing almsot the same thing except in a broader way (not just in the ckeditor instances but also all inputs that have a certain class). I will mark your answer for anyone who needs an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

check out ckeditor documents, there is an option called 'blockedKeystrokes'.

http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.blockedKeystrokes